# erlang template engine. sgte, google-cTemplate, or erlydtl

Tags: erlang, template-engine

I am planning to implement a template engine to my erlang project, and the most important thing is the performance. Currently I have a lot of Velocity Java template, and I want to migrate templates available to erlang.

I googled it, and found things like;

- http://www.ivan.fomichev.name/2008/05/erlang-template-engine-prototype.html
- erlydtl
- google-ctemplate
- sgte

Pure erlang implementation would be the best, but c(c++) based template engine, i.e. google-ctemplate, performs better, I would use it with erlang linked in driver.

Have no experience on this matter yet, so anyone's suggestions would be super great.

thanks

Answer (score 5):

My personal favourite is erlydtl. It compiles the template to an erlang module, so there's no filesystem access or parsing time consumed when you call 'render'.

I think rebar has erlydtl support these days, so getting your templates compiled is a lot less hassle than it used to be. Just name them `*.dtl` and they'll get built when you run `rebar compile`.

It should also be fairly competitive speed wise as it's in-process (skip the IPC cost of a port program), compiled (and could be compiled to native code if you wanted to), and generates iolists which are pretty efficient.

Comment: +1 Erlang can be surprisingly fast (and sometimes slow) but if you know what you are doing it can outperforms c(c++) based solutions just because it uses some nice but uncommon approaches like iolists as example.